# How do I let the object move / or where is the error?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to make an object move automatically on the screen.
**html**

```
<body>
<h1>Hallo</h1>
<div id='bird'></div>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
let elemBird = document.getElementById('movingBird');
let birdSpeed = 2;
let birdisAlive = true;
let pos = {
    x: -150,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight),
    endX: window.innerWidth,
    endY: window.innerHeight,
};
```

in the lower part I create a Div-Container with ID and an Img-Tag on which I ...

```
function createBird() {
    const bird = document.createElement('div');
    bird.className = 'animation';
    bird.id = 'movingBird';
    const birdImg = document.createElement('img');
    birdImg.src = './assets/Koli.jpeg';
    birdImg.className = 'bird-style';
    bird.appendChild(birdImg);
    document.getElementById('bird').appendChild(bird);
}


function movingDown() {
    pos.x += birdSpeed + (Math.random() * 5);
    pos.y += birdSpeed + (Math.random() * 15);
}
```

...which should then move with the moveBird() function

```
function moveBird() {
    let id;
    if (pos.x <= pos.endX) {
        if (birdisAlive) {
            pos.x += birdSpeed;
        } else if (pos.y <= pos.endY) {
            movingDown();
        }
        elemBird.style.transform = `translate(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px)`;
        id = requestAnimationFrame(moveBird);
    } else {
        cancelAnimationFrame(id);
    }
}

createBird();
moveBird();
```

Why do I get the error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

(I have the same setup without the pos-object and this works. But my attempt is to let several objects move at the same time.)

Comment: because you reference `document.getElementById('movingBird');` before you create it

Comment: is your js running after the dom finish loading?

Comment: thx @epascarello; now it Works